# Objective -c, removeFromSuperview not works every time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am trying to remove a view, sometimes it works fine , and sometimes not. I am beginner. I don't know what the problem. I am frustrated. Please let me know what the problem.my code :

```
-(void)hideNotification
{   
    btnNotification.selected=NO;
    btnHome.selected=YES;
    [notificationScreen.view removeFromSuperview];
    notificationScreen=nil;
    isNotificationScreen=NO;
}
```

I have also tried : **dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         [notificationScreen.view removeFromSuperview];
});**   and **`performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];`** but not succeeded.

Comment: What is `notificationScreen`? Where is it defined, created, destroyed, replaced? Have you debugged to check you have a reference to it, and that it't the correct instance?

Answer (score -1):

First and foremost thing I would check in this situation is to ensure updating my UI only on main thread. Trusting, you have already tried that out.

Next, per [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/removeFromSuperview), I would ensure following things:

> If the view’s superview is not nil, the superview releases the view.
>   Never call this method from inside your view’s `drawRect:` method.

Finally, unsure how your `notificationScreen` object looks like, I would try to set a tag on the view to be removed and remove it based on the tag value. Not sure if `notificationScreen` refers to your current view controller in which your above code will now work. Try this out:

1. Set the tag of the view that you want to be removed
   (`myNotificationView.tag = 1`) when initializing and adding to its parent view.
2. When you are ready to remove the notification view, do it like this

`for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews] ) { 
     if (view.tag == 1 ) {
       [view removeFromSuperview]; 
     } 
}`

For step 2, you could have a strong reference to your notification view and call `removeFromSuperview` on that object.

Comment: Using tags to identify a view is brittle and unlikely to be a solution to the problem.

Comment: Yes thats why I gave to use the property. To troubleshoot the issue, tag option was suggested.

Answer (score -1):

First you need to check your view is subview or not. Just change code like below:

```
-(void)hideNotification
{   
    btnNotification.selected=NO;
    btnHome.selected=YES;
    if([notificationScreen.view isDescendantOfView:self.view]){
         [notificationScreen.view removeFromSuperview];
     }
    notificationScreen=nil;
    isNotificationScreen=NO;
}
```

Comment: This makes no difference. If the view doesn't have a superview then `removeFromSuperview` has no effect. This is just adding a redundant call.